# Printing an array using recursion

Tags: optimization

Printing an array using recursion is much slower as compared to printing an array using iteration. Why? Is iteration always faster than recursion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651112/is-recursion-ever-faster-than-looping

Answer (score 1):

It takes most (when not all) compilers more time to call a function, then to jump back with the programmcounter. (The number that indicates which line gets executed.)

When a function gets executed, its parameters and return-adress have to be registered on the stack.